# Binding causes my viewmodel to stay in memory

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have a window that I open from my main window like so

```
Views.VTestWindow searchViewTest = new VTestWindow(myUser.UserID);
searchViewTest.Closed += SearchViewTest_Closed;
searchViewTest.DataContext = searchContext;
searchViewTest.ShowDialog();
```

I have several controls in the view bound to the viewModel. The one giving me heartburn is a combobox. I have its selectedIndex bound to a property on my VM. If I remove that binding my profiler says the VM gets disposed. However with if I have the binding there and the comboBox gets opened(doesn't have to change selection) the profiler says my VM still exists after dispose has been called.
ComboBox code

```
<ComboBox Width="150" MinHeight="25" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedSearchBy}">
      <ComboBox.Items>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Order Number" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Recent Orders" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Account (Not Shipped)" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Account (Shipped)" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Account (All)" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Account (Cancelled)" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Express" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Status" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Needs To Be Released" />
      </ComboBox.Items>
</ComboBox>
```

Could anyone tell me why this would happen or better yet how I would go about fixing it? I have double check to make sure I don't have any event handlers still in use. Cleared all lists that the VM would use.
My application is rather large and I am seeing crashes from memory usage so I am trying to find every little thing that I can that is causing memory issues.

Here is my close to my Window

```
void SearchViewTest_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    VTestWindow searchViewTest = sender as VTestWindow;
    searchViewTest.Closed -= SearchViewTest_Closed;
    VmOrderSearch searchContext = searchViewTest.DataContext as VmOrderSearch;
    //Do Stuff here

    searchContext.Dispose();
    searchViewTest.DataContext = null;
    searchViewTest = null;
}
```

Comment: have you tried setting the DataContext to null in the closed event?

Comment: Have you ran a CLR profiler and compared the memory prints of these two scenarios? What object is holding a reference to your VM in your second case?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code line to an appropriate place:

```
searchViewTest.Closed -= SearchViewTest_Closed;
```

Comment: I remove that inside the closed event. As I stated, if I don't open the combobox. The VM will dispose properly.

Comment: Inside the close event? This sounds weird. Or do you mean inside `SearchViewTest_Closed`?